# Reproduce Error in Chartjs v2 Polar chart not plotting all supplied data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

While its more than likely an error of my own making could someone help me. 
I have a polarchart with 6 datapoints that only displays 5 datapoints when plotted. 
If its an issue I'll open 1 on GitHub but I was thinking that if its down to my poor code maybe its worth opening an issue to prevent others having the same issue

Using only the chartjs available via CDN link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0/Chart.js , jquery 1.12.3 and the following script in a basic html file 
can anyone reproduce the issue where the chart has 6 labels, **6** data points but **only plots 5 **

All files included in uploaded zip file

[PolarChart.zip](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/files/236250/PolarChart.zip)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = $("#mypolar").get(0).getContext("2d");

        // Polar Chart Data
        //labels "Communicate ", "Create ", "Find & Use", "Identity & Wellbeing", "Teach & Learn", "Tools & Technology"
        var data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4],
        backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360","#F7554A"],
        label: 'My dataset' // for legend
    }],
    labels: ["Communicate & Collaboarate", "Create & innovate", "Find & Use", "Identity & Wellbeing", "Teach & Learn","Tools & Technology"]
};

    //Plot the Radar Chart
    var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: data,
    //options: options 
    });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your points are being plotted (if you count the number of sectors there are 6 sectors). The problem was that your scale was beginning from the lowest value (1 - the value of your first point) causing nothing to be seemingly plotted for the 1st point.

You can override the scale to begin from 0 if you want to show all points

```
...
options: {
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero:true
      }
    }
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ja08nzm5/

Comment: Could I ask for a bit of extra help setting other options for my chart like making it non-responsive. My js coding skills is terrible

Comment: Here's how you make it non-responsive - http://jsfiddle.net/6h4102pz/ (just add the responsive: false and specify a height and width for your canvas element)